# Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas error when using joi-password-complexity

Tags: node.js, joi

I am having some trouble integrating [joi-password-complexity](https://github.com/kamronbatman/joi-password-complexity) into my Joi validation logic. The error I get is `Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas`. What do I need to change?

schemasShared.js

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const JoiPasswordComplexity = require('joi-password-complexity');

const joiPasswordComplexityOptions = {
    min: 10,
    max: 50,
    lowerCase: 1,
    upperCase: 1,
    numeric: 1,
    symbol: 1,
    requirementCount: 4,
};

const passwordLogin = new JoiPasswordComplexity(
    joiPasswordComplexityOptions
);


module.exports = {
    passwordLogin
};
```

auth.schemas.js

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const schemasShared = require('../../utils/schemasShared');

const authRequirements = {
    password: schemasShared.passwordLogin,
}

const authSchemas = {
    loginBody: Joi.object({ // The error points to this line, specifically to .object
        password: authRequirements
            .password
            .required(),
    }),
}
```

My versions:

- "@hapi/joi": "^16.1.7"
- "joi-password-complexity": "^3.1.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in v4.0: [joi-password-complexity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-password-complexity).

Also v4.0 supports Joi v16/17

Comment: I can confirm that it works with 4.0 of joi-password-complexity. Do note that in `const passwordLogin = new JoiPasswordComplexity(
    joiPasswordComplexityOptions
);`, you now have to remove the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you can use overrides in package Json to use same version for other dependent packages

```
    "hapi-swagger": {
      "swagger-ui-dist": "3.X.X",
      "joi": "16.X.X"
    }
```